# SlowCheetah 2.5.2 broken when publishing Winform Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, publish, visual-studio-extensions, slowcheetah

After upgrading to SlowCheetah 2.5.2 today, publishing a WinForm application to a network drive does no longer work.

For some strange reason the App.config file, which there has to be made some transformation on, is no longer part of the deployed files :-( And therefore the Winform Application does not work.

This morning i did deploy without any problems, then Visual Studio 2012 informed me about the update to SlowCheetah which i installed, and notived later that the publishing was broken.

When i go into the projects properties setting and select 'Publish' and click on 'Application Files' the ProgramName.exe.config is sometimes shown, other times not, it is Included, required, but it does not end up in the deployed files folder.

I solved the problem, by deleting the App.config + release and debug files, added a App.config again, and got the ProgramName.exe.config content from an earlier published version and put it into App.config. Then it worked again.

So i think it is the transformation somehow going wrong :-(
Not completly sure it's SlowCheetah, but i did not change anything else on the computer or in Visual Studio 2012.

Does anyone know a way to fix this problem? I have not been able to find an earlier version of SlowCheetah :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I think I introduced a bug here. I have updated [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) and the updates should resolve this. Can you try it out and let me know if you have any further issues?

It should be resolved with the changes in [these](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/commit/f3cafcc4549f2c0aa26030d92150738ee2277f87) [commits](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/commit/1f90325f2d1a72f221fe116289c1a8c14c43ccfa).